# Wearing a candy-bracelet tied using red string outside an Eruv on Shabbos

Tags: shabbat, food, hotzaa-carrying-reshuyot, marit-ayin, reshuth-harabim-public-domain

What are the Halachic ramifications of wearing a Western Wall red string (which people consider clothing) which has candies tied to it (like a candy-bracelet) on Shabbos outside an Eruv? Is it considered clothing if the wearer enjoys both the candies on it and the string itself, and would anyways wear it even without the candies?

Would one be allowed to chew the candies while outside an Eruv?

Is licking food outside an Eruv any different?

Would Mares Ayin forbid this act, because others won't know that this is a dual-purpose bracelet, or could that be avoided with a specially-made red candy bracelet?

Comment: I’m not at all certain it is permitted to wear the red string in the first place without an eruv.

Comment: But isn't jewelry permitted without an Eruv? Doesn't it become part of the person?

Comment: Regarding red strings: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17432

Comment: Aside from any Avodah Zara, is there a prohibition of Hotza'a?

Comment: @Moish Jewelry isn’t necessarily permitted. It’s a complex topic. Only some items qualify as jewelry, and perhaps it is only permitted for women. Sounds like a good (separate) question to ask.

Comment: See https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12903/wearing-a-gold-watch-on-shabbos-without-an-eiruv?rq=1

Comment: I've completely revamped my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT: The answer completely revamped***

First, consult your rabbi, I just offer discussion here.

That being said, assuming that the red string is OK to carry and it's a jewelry ("accessory"), question is, are the candies are part of the jewelry - meaning is it "cool" to hang around with candies on your wrist, or is it just a way to carry them? if so, There is a discussion about if jewelry are permitted for men where there is no *eiruv*:

רא"ש שבת פ"ז סי' י

מעשה בר"ג שירד לטייל בתוך חצרו בשבת ומפתח של זהב בידו וגערו בו חביריו משום תכשיט הדא אמרת העשוי לתכשיט אסור. הדא אמרת העשוי לכך ולכך...לאיש ולאשה ... וי"מ העשוי לכך ולכך כלומר שעשוי לתכשיט ולתשמיש כמו מפתח שפותח בו המנעול בזה אסור בין באיש בין באשה דהרואה אומר לצורך תשמיש הוא מוציאו. ... ובאשכנז נוהגין שעושין מפתחות ותולות הנשים אותן בצואריהן בשלשלאות של כסף או בחוטי צבעונין ויוצאין בהן

Ra"sh Shabbat 7:10

Raban Gamliel went for a walk on *Shabbat* in his yard, with a golden key in his hand, and he was rebuked by his freinds, you learn that [an object] made for jewelry is forbidden, you learn the [also when the object is] made for *both*... To *both* men and women... and some explain the it's made for both jewelry and other use, that kind of object are forbidden for men and women, beacuse the viewer tells that the object is used for something else, and not jewelry... And on Ashkenaz women wear keys on silver chains or color strings as necklaces.

How do we handle this Ra"sh?

ב"י טור או"ח שא

ולפי דברי המפרשים דהעשוי לכך ולכך דהיינו שעשוי לתכשיט ולתשמיש הדבר ברור דהני מפתחות אסור וכמו שכתב רבינו אבל הרא"ש משמע דאינו מפרש העשוי לכך ולכך ... ולכן כתב שבאשכנז נוהגים היתר ולא נחלק עליהם ... אבל מנהג אשכנז שהמפתח קשור בצואר ליכא למיחש להכי דהא יכולה לאחוויי בעוד המפתח עליה וגם אינו נקל כ"כ למשלפיה הלכך שרי אף לאשה

Beit Yossef Tur O"A 301

According to the opinions that "both" refers to jewelry and other use you cannot carry keys as jewelry on *Shabbt*, but it seems that the Ra"sh does not think like this, that's why he mentioned the Ashkentz custom , that the key is attached to the neck, so [the women] can show it while it's on her, and it's not easily removed, that's why is allowed even for a women...

According to the B"Y, maybe [*if* we accept that candies can be seen as jewel, like a silver key, and that is a big if.] it would be allowed since the candies are not easily removed from the bracelet.

דרישה או"ח שא

> לכן נ"ל דמ"ש רבינו וכן דבר העשוי לתכשיט להשתמש בו כו' אסור לפסק הלכה
> כתב כן ... ובאשכנז ... כלומר ... דוקא בענין זה שתולות בצוואריהם כו'
> אבל אינם מוציאות אותם בידם שהרואה אומר לצורך תשמיש כו'...

Drisha O"H 301

It seems that what the Ra"sh wrote, that it's forbidden ["both" means jewelry and other use], it's he's opinion, and what happen in Ashkentaz.. it means that ... only at this fashion, that the key is hanged on their necks, so the viewer will not say that the key is for another use...

According to the Drisha, it will be forbidden since the viewer may still say that the candies are meant to be eaten.

However, those two opinions, are just if the candies are really just accessory, but what happens if they actually meant  to be for beauty *and* to be eaten?

שו"ע או"ח שא ס י"א

> ואם המפתח של נחושת וברזל אפילו מחובר וקבוע בחגורה אסור ... ויש שכתבו
> שנוהגין בזה להתיר ...

S"A O"H 301:11

... and if the key is copper or iron...even if attached to the belt taking out is forbidden, and other opinion says it's allowed.

ט"ז או"ח ש"א

> ביאור דברים אלו הם לפע"ד בדרך זה דיש שני דרכים להתיר בענין זה דהיינו
> האחד מצד תכשיט... שנית מצד שהוא בטל לגבי דבר אחר כגון שקשור בסוף
> האיזור ובזה כתב מהר"ם דיש היתר בשל כסף מצד שהוא תכשיט ובסה"מ...בענין
> שא"א להפרד משם כי הוא מדובק בברזל של המפתח והם כחתיכה א' דאז מותר מטעם
> שהמפתח בטל לגבי חגורה ארוכה שיש בה זינק"ל...

T"Z O"H 301

That means, that there are two ways to allow these object, Fist, that they are considered as jewel...The second, if the object is secondary to other object, like being a buckle at the end of the belt, that's where the Mahar"m Shi"f [that allows even iron key] says that silver [key] is allowed since it's a jewel and S"ham says... If it's attached to the key's Iron it's allowed since they are one piece, because the [iron] key is secondary to the belt that has a buckle...

According to T"z, it will be hard to allow this, because for the Maram Sh"if it's pretty hard to see candies as bracelet beads [so it's more like an iron key and not a silver key], but maybe for the S"Ham it would be allowed since the candies are attached well to the bracelet.

Comment: I once saw someone wearing a key necklace on Shabbos in a place with an eruv.  I said to her "you don't use the eruv??" (not that that's an unheard of chumra, but I was surprised that this person followed it).  She said "no I do, this key doesn't even open anything, it's just a necklace".  It made me happy that people actually wear those kinds of necklaces.

Comment: @Heshy Maybe someday you will find someone that use his house key as a buckle...